# How to deploy Node Js ,Express,and Mongo DB app to the Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I have created an app using Express,Node.JS,and mongo db.I want to deploy it on my windows server 2012 R2.Please let me know the process.

Comment: You want to deploy it in IIS?

Comment: @rmjoia yes i want to deploy in IIS on windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 0):

I use IIS NODE [Hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). The installation process is very straightforward, yet, If any questions, please install the sample projects as described on the product repo or refer to the [IIS Node HowTos](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode#howtos)

I use the configuration you mentioned but with SQL (for the moment).

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep the Node Process running. 
The best way is to use process managers like [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)
You can directly deploy using PM2 or You can use IIS/Apache as a gateway server.